# Layered Navigation not working using elastic search 6.0+

Tags: layered-navigation, magento2.3.2, elasticsearch

i am using elastic search 6.0+ and porto theme with magento 2.3.2 , using mageplaza layered navigation but when i click in any filter gave 500 error on console and front end show without css.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurred due to getCollectionClone() function.
You can use Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection instead of Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection in filter file.

The patch is now released in layer navigation extension and it's compatible with Elastic Search 6+.